# How to combine two objects with same key name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array-merge

In my react app, I currently have two arrays with objects that I would like to combine.

```js
  const cars = [ 
    {'car': 'porsche', 'description': 'luxury', 'driverId': 4},
    {'car': 'ferrari', 'description': 'beatiful', 'driverId': 2},
    {'car': 'bmw', 'description': 'slow', 'driverId': 5} 
    ]

  const drivers = [
    {'driver':{'car': 'kia', 'name':'John' , 'description': 'Overweight'}},
    {'driver':{'car': 'toyota', 'name':'Koko' , 'description': 'Ugly looking'}},
    {'driver':{'car': 'nissan', 'name':'Goku' , 'description': 'Tall'}}
    ]
```

After combining two objects, I would like end result to be like this.

```js
   const carInfo = [
    {'car': 'porsche', 'description': 'luxury', 'driverId': 4, 'carName':'kia', 'name':'John' , 'descriptionDriver': 'Overweight'},
    {'car': 'ferrari', 'description': 'beatiful', 'driverId': 2, 'carName': 'toyota', 'name':'Koko' , 'descriptionDriver': 'Ugly looking'},
    {'car': 'bmw', 'description': 'slow', 'driverId': 5, 'carName': 'nissan', 'name':'Goku' , 'descriptionDriver': 'Tall'}
    ]
```

Basically, I would like to change the key name in drivers object then combine them. Because spread operator wouldn't work when there are same key name between objects. How can I get this result?

Comment: Are the two arrays always guaranteed to be the same length? What should happen if they're not?

Comment: Why not just insert each `driver` object under the key `driver`? Then you don't need to worry about conflicting object keys

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can use spread operator, just map over it and "rename" some props:

```
drivers.map(x => x.driver).map((x, i) => {
  let { car, description, ...rest } = x
  return { ...rest, carName: car, descriptionDriver: description, ...cars[i] }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out beautifully!